# Difference b/w char* str[],char *str and char str[]

Tags: c++, c, pointers, char

What is the difference b/w:

```
function(char* str )
function(char* str[] )
function(char str[] )
```

and how are they called (by which type of `string`/`char[]`)?

Comment: And who told you SO is a tutorial service? Please let us know why google could not answer your question.

Comment: Kindly google such questions

Answer (score 1):

> function(char* str )

function taking a pointer to char, you call it like following:

```
char arr[10];
function(arr); // here arr is actually a char[] type,but it decays to char*
```

inside function you have no knowledge of arr length

> ,function(char* str[] )

this is an array of pointers to char, you can use it like:

```
char arr1[] = "foo";
char arr2[] = "fai";
char arr3[] = "foo";
char* sarr[] { arr1, arr2, arr3 }; 
function(sarr); // here also no length of sarr is known inside function, you should pass is as second argument
```

> and function(char str[] )

this is a function taking char[] type as str parameter, you can use it like:

```
char aa[12] = { "asd" };
function(aa);
```

I dont see any huge difference between function(char* str ) and function(char str[] ). Compiler will not even allow you to overload function with such arguments:

```
void function (char str[]); // compiler sees it as char* str
void function (char* str);
```

generates errror.

function(char* str[] ) on the other hand is completly different, because you have array of char pointers instead of an array of chars

Comment: the last example is not the safest. if `f` does change the `char[]` - changing a string literal has an undefined behaviour

Comment: @DavidHaimI think its fine, this is an array initialization, you can modify it inside function. The problem is rather with `char* sarr[] { "foo", "fai", "foo" };` `char*` should be `const char*`

Comment: "I dont see any huge difference..." because there isn't any. They are identical functions. You can absolutely write those declarations consecutively, since they are just redeclarations - you just can't define both.

Answer (score 0):

function (char *str) is the same as function (char str[]) and are functions that take char array as a parameter .
function (char *str[]) is a function that take an array of char array as parameter.

These function can be called using pointers 
example:

function (char *str[])
char **x ....
function (x);

Comment: Are you sure that they are the same  ? or you mean that they are treated the same ? I'm just asking.

Answer (score 0):

char *s is pointer to char

char s[] is an Array

char *s[] is array of pointers to char.

But When they are used as function arguments then

```
char *s and char s[]
```

and

```
char *s[] and char **s
```

are treated the same.

this means that the following:

```
int foo(char s[] , char *s[]){
  /* code  */
}
```

is the same as :

```
int foo(char *s, char **s){
/* code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `f( T a[] )` and `f( T *a )` mean exactly the same thing; `a` is declared as a pointer to `T`.  `f( T *a[] )` declares `a` as a pointer to pointer to `T`.

This is a holdover from the B programming language (from which C was derived), where `a[]` declared `a` as a pointer.

For a regular object declaration, `T a[]` declares `a` as an array of unkown size; the declaration is *incomplete*, and `a` cannot be used until it has been defined with a size.